# Best way to have a variable amount of DataGrids?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

So I have a SQL Database with a lot of tables in it. I'm trying to display the tables in a Datagrid on a simple asp.net site. Each table will have its own datagrid. The problem I'm having is, depending on which options the user selects my dataset will return anywhere from 3-7 tables. Because of this all the tables are unnamed e.g.:

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter dataAdpt = new SqlDataAdapter();
...
dataAdpt.SelectCommand = m_cmd;
dataAdpt.Fill(dataSet);
```

I'm then returning this to a method that will create the datagrids. Here is what I have:

```
private void createDataGrid(DataSet dataSet)
{
    foreach (DataTable table in dataSet.Tables)
    {
        DataGrid grid = new DataGrid();
        grid.DataSource = new DataView(table);
        grid.DataBind();
    }
}
```

But because the grids are not defined in my **Default.aspx** it isn't displaying anything. I'm new to asp.net in general so suggestions on how to better accomplish this are very welcome. But in general is there a way I can just "add" the table to the page dynamically?

Comment: Have a `Repeater` that has a bunch of datagrids in it.  Bind the collection of datatables to the repeater, and have the repeater bind each datatable to the datagrid.

Comment: You should most certainly use the method @Servy mentions. This is *by far* the best-practice in this situation.

Comment: I agree that it's more elegant, but if the OP is a beginner and he's just wanting to see results, that's considerably more work.

Comment: @Cortright And considerably less likely to cause problems that he won't know how to solve.  Giving him something that appears like it will work, but that will cause all sorts of problems he's ill-equipped to solve is irresponsible.  He should take the time to learn how to properly solve the problem instead of having to un-learn a bunch of poor practices after being burned by them first.

Comment: Well then let's put a disclaimer here for him.  OP, if you want to do anything with the datagrids after you throw them on the page, you are much better off going with the repeater approach.  However, if you just want to display the data and that's it - the placeholder approach is fine.

Comment: I'd like to go with the more accepted practice if I can. But its hard to find good resources to learn this stuff. Do you know of any?

Comment: This previously-asked question details the method Servy was talking about.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604732/asp-net-datagrid-within-a-repeater
(I would also echo the sentiment that you should look at using GridView instead)
 
Where to learn this stuff - personally I learn best by doing things myself, but everyone is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a placeholder on the page in the aspx.

```
<asp:placeholder id="phGrids" runat="server" />
```

Then, just after your databind in your codebehind that you've pasted, do:

```
phGrids.Controls.Add(grid);
```